# Sort data frame based on the value of a column and the length of a list in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a datframe such as:

```
Employee      list_of_children              child

Jonathen      ['John', 'Bob','Jennifer']    John

Jonathen      ['John', 'Bob','Jennifer']    Bob

Jonathen      ['John', 'Bob','Jennifer']    Jennifer

Emily         ['Clark']                     Clark

Hans          ['Watson', 'Hans Jr']         Watson

Hans          ['Watson', 'Hans Jr']         Watson
```

How do I sort the above dataframe so that the employee with least children is first?

```
Employee      list_of_children              child

Emily         ['Clark']                     Clark

Hans          ['Watson', 'Monica']         Watson

Hans          ['Watson', 'Monica']         Monica

Jonathen      ['John', 'Bob','Jennifer']    John

Jonathen      ['John', 'Bob','Jennifer']    Bob

Jonathen      ['John', 'Bob','Jennifer']    Jennifer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do with `argsort` after get the `len`

```
df = df.iloc[df['list_of_children'].str.len().argsort()]
```

Comment: Why are you turning list to string? ```["hello", "world"]``` is shorter than ```["HELLLLLLLOOOOOOOOOOOO"]```

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa this is not turn list to str , this is count the len of list , ["hello", "world"] return 2  ["HELLLLLLLOOOOOOOOOOOO"] return 1